# How to pass array data to jQuery dialog and display?

Tags: jquery

Hello I am trying to pass array data into the jquery dialog box and display. I haven't had much luck with this and Im guessing my whole approach to this is wrong. Any guidance to the right way is much appreciated.

```
<html>
<div id="confirm"></div>
</html>

<script>
var array_data = ["London", "NewYork", "Miami" , "LosAngeles"];

$('#confirm').html(array_data).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Confirmation message',
    buttons: {
          Submit: function () { //Do Something here };
          Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    },
     width: 850, height: 300
}).dialog('open');

</script>
```

I'm unable to figure out how I would pass the array object to the modal and then print out the array values one by one.

Comment: May I know when are you planning to print out the array values? Would you want to print it out on open of the dialog?

Comment: That's where i'm confused. I'm not sure if my approach to this is right. All I want is when the dialog opens the array needs to be printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to print out the array values on open of the dialog, then, you may attach an open event to the dialog. You may want to check out: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

So in your case, you may do it this way:

```
<html>
<div id="confirm"></div>
</html>

<script>
var array_data = ["London", "NewYork", "Miami" , "LosAngeles"];

$(document).bind("ready", function(){
$('#confirm').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Confirmation message',
    buttons: {
          Submit: function () { },
          Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    },
     width: 850, height: 300,
     open: function(event, ui) {
        $(array_data).each(function(index, data){
           console.log(data);
        });
     }
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: This did not work. I get a Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 error. How about I write the array items to a div, hide the div on page load and then display the div when I click a button ? Will that be a good approach ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. At that point the div node has not been created yet, hence, the error gets thrown. You need to instantiate the dialog when the document is ready. I have edited the code above to run instantiation of the dialog when the div node has been created already.

Comment: Even this wouldnt work. I'm getting the Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'.

Comment: I see. I think you failed to add the necessary scripts. Did you add the jquery and jquery ui scripts to the header? Kindly check: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ to see which scripts need to be added to the header. You may click on View Source at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed the jQueryUI script. What I now see is the array elements in the console when I run it on chrome. But it doesnt appear in the modal.

Comment: I used JSON.stringify method to serialize the array object and then write to a div to display the array values. It works beautifully as expected. Many thanks for your help and guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely passing an array to dailog will not work as it cannot interpret what is stored in it. Try using jQuery.each(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) and extract each of the element and pass to the logic.